# Reading multiple .nc files

Tags: matlab, plot, time-series, netcdf

I have many.nc files named as 'MERRA2_100.tavg1_2d_rad_Nx.**19800101**.SUB.nc' from **19800101** to **20180330** (yyyymmdd) containing variables CLDHGH, CLDLOW, CLDMID, CLDTOT with dimensions 65*80*24.

How to make a time series plot for one variable 'CLDHGH' for complete time period (1980-01-01 to 2018-03-30) using these files?????

I made timeseries plot for CLDHGH for a day (24 hours) using this code:

```
cldhigh = ncread('D:\cloudnc\MERRA2_100.tavg1_2d_rad_Nx.19800101.SUB.nc','CLDHGH');
cldhigh(cldhigh==0)=NaN;
cldhighmean=nanmean(cldhigh);
cldhighmean2=nanmean(cldhighmean,2);
CLDHGH=reshape(cldhighmean2,[24 1]);
ts1=timeseries(CLDHGH,1:24);
ts1.Name= 'High Cloud';
ts1.TimeInfo.Units = 'hours';

plot(ts1);
```

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: How to make a time series plot for one variable 'CLDHGH' for complete time period (1980-01-01 to 2018-03-30)??

Comment: http://mathforum.org/kb/message.jspa?messageID=9841659

Answer (score 0):

You can read all files, extract the date, put them in the right order

```
d = dir('*.nc');
for ct = 1:length(d)
    n=d(ct).name;
    date = datetime(n(28:35),'Format','yyyyMMdd');
    times = date+hours(0:23);
end
```

This code first makes a structure that has the properties of all files that have `.nc` as extension. Then it for-loops over them and extracts the name, puts it in `n`. From n you can get the data using `datetime`, because it seems your date is always in character `28 to 35`. If it is not, use `regexpr` to find it. Final line adds the 24 hours to the found date so you have a time-vector to use with the plot.

From this point you should be able to put in your own code and get it to work.

Comment: after this? to read files together??  ncread(?????, 'CLDHGH'); and so on...

Comment: I tried with this code, nd can serve my purpose till 9 only;       for i=1:9
    cld=['D:\cloudnc\MERRA2_100.tavg1_2d_rad_Nx.1980010',num2str(i),'.SUB.nc'];
    cldhigh(:,:,:,i) = ncread(cld,'CLDHGH');
end

Comment: Not surprising. You convert a number to string, if you go to 10 your date would be `198001010`. but the 10th of october 19800 is too far in the future.

Comment: I already gave you a direction in this answer. I will not just write you the program that does what you want. You would need to contact an ICT consultancy firm for that, not SO. :-)